# How to disable visitor's scrolling and allow scroll only on click scrolling to div (<a href="#div">)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to disable visitor's scrolling with scroll bar or scroll wheel on mouse and allow only to scroll down with  button image .

I tried to add "overflow: hidden" but it just mess up website, demo: [here](http://csgotale.com/stackoverflow-demo-my-try/index.html).
And here is demo of my website (with scroll bar and scroll wheel mouse allowed): [click here](http://csgotale.com/stackoverflow-demo-allowed/index.html).
Any helps? Thanks.

PS. if im going to get negative ragings and reputation again, please provide any comment with reason why are you giving negative reputation always.

Comment: 1) Please add code in the question. 2) Try to Give your public code in a JSFiddle so that you've shown you've isolated the problem. Giving the code in your prod environment like that means there could be many other variables affecting your results.

Comment: I added two demos. There is no much useful codes except I used "overflow: hidden" . I've already said that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery, just in you `index.html` file at the top add this line of code :

```
  jQuery(document.body).css('overflow', 'hidden')
```

Let me be more precisely, in your code it would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //ADD HERE 
  jQuery(document.body).css('overflow', 'hidden')

  $("a").on('click', function(event) {  
    if (this.hash !== "") {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;
      $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800, function(){
      window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      }
    });
});
```

And it will work!